# Having both value and placeholder possible in form input?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm looking to have both value and placeholder at an input field... the value would be more like twitter's @mention... it's the text the user need to have to start the input, and the placeholder gives hint to what user needs to type.

It seems like this can't be accomplished with only html

But is there anyway to make this possible in javascript or other means?

[image]

Comment: This *is* possible in HTML. Use both attributes: `value` and `placeholder`. http://jsfiddle.net/se6ot0xq/

Comment: Please describe twitter's @mention for those who don't have twitter. "gives a hint" is too broad.

Comment: He wants them both visible, if you set value, placeholder is not shown.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question is answered in the specification for [HTML input tags](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input) - primarily, that both `value` and `placeholder` are valid attributes, a direct rebuttal of the question.

Comment: @rockerest: I only see them one at a time.  Is it because the value is overlapping the placeholder?  From how I see it, if value is there, placeholder isn't visible.  Am i wrong?

Comment: @Novina That is absolutely the behavior of a placeholder. If content is not present in the field (a value), the placeholder is visible to hint at what should be there. As you say in your question "the placeholder gives hint to what user needs to type". This is precisely the behavior you want as described. If that's not correct, perhaps you can create an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to demonstrate.

Comment: @rockerest: added a graphic representation of it.

Comment: @oriol: see the picture added

Comment: @Novina I think that's a textarea, not an input.

Comment: @oriol: input/textarea.  I need either one to work, I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use either two input fields (one with value and one with hint) or just use a label to tell the user the string always starts with @mention (or something else).

In the code to handle the input you then append both strings.

Comment: That's what I was going to do, but it doesn't create the effect above, mainly the way the text wrap like one rectangle.  So I'm hoping there's a way to "hack" it. ;)

Comment: Well I guess you can add the predefined text using css absolute to look like it is in the textbox, and using padding or whitespace to place the hint after that.