# Prevent value from overriding placeholder - Inputs HTML

Tags: html

I want to use a placeholder as a description for a input box. I also want the default value to be 50.

However, if value is set, it overrides the placeholder:

```html
<input name="freq" type="number" placeholder="Frequency (Hz)" value="50">
```

Is there any way to have both the description and the default value?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```html
<input name="freq" type="number" placeholder="Frequency (Hz)" onfocus="this.value=50">
```

If you want to display the `placeholder`, you cannot set `value` when the script is loaded.

However after the users have read the placeholder and attempt to input some value (i.e. click into the `input` element, which is triggered by the `onfocus` event), you can set the default value (by setting `this.value` which refer to the `input` element's value to your default).

Comment: this will reset the value to 50 (i.e. the value in the "onfocus" attribute) again if you focus/select the field after having set another value...

Comment: Nice solution, thank you! I notice when using the arrow buttons on the input that it starts at zero. Is there a way for that to also start at this.value?

Comment: @Johannes is definitely right, but the problem is easy to fix by adding an if-else statement to check the current value. Also, my goal is to give some alternative or direction for OP only, so I will just leave this issue for OP to fix lol.

Comment: @WillPowell the arrow is working fine for me, maybe you can try testing the code in a `html` file or you can give us more info on your issue.

Comment: @ytung-dev what I mean is when you click on the up or down arrow (without clicking inside the input box itself) it starts at zero.

Comment: In my browser the arrows are wrapped inside the `input` element, maybe you can try `onchange` (trigger when value is changed) event too to cater your concern.

Answer (score 1):

Having both value and placeholder is not possible. What you can do is to add the predefined text using css absolute to look it like a placeholder in the Input. Also pls check this [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33484063/having-both-value-and-placeholder-possible-in-form-input)